# Android: Twitter in WebView - Back to an Activity by callback

Tags: android, twitter, android-activity, webview, back

I try to create Twitter client and now I deal with authorization via OAuth protocol. I have created "Sign In" button to come in WebView and load twitter authorization URL, that's work. However, when the authorization is accepted successfuly and Twitter service redirect me to my callback I receive error web page in WebView. That is to say I am not redirected to my activity, I still stay in WebView. But if try the same way via browser, it`s working. What the problem is that?

Main Activivty:

```
    public class Twitter extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    Button bSignIn;
    TextView status;
    private OAuthConsumer consumer;
    private OAuthProvider provider;
    private String url;
    final String TAG = getClass().getName();

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.home);

        bSignIn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bSignIn);
        status = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvStatus);
        bSignIn.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    public void onClick(View v) {
        new OAuthWebViewProcess().execute();
    }

    public class OAuthWebViewProcess extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        ProgressDialog dialog;

        protected void onPreExecute() {
            dialog = ProgressDialog.show(Twitter.this, null,
                    "Connecting, please wait...");
        }

        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            try {
            consumer = new CommonsHttpOAuthConsumer(Constants.CONSUMER_KEY,
                    Constants.CONSUMER_SECRET);
            provider = new CommonsHttpOAuthProvider(Constants.REQUEST_URL,
                    Constants.ACCESS_URL, Constants.AUTHORIZE_URL);
            url = provider.retrieveRequestToken(consumer,
                        Constants.OAUTH_CALLBACK_URL);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Error during OAUth retrieve request token", e);
            }
            return null;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            //Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
            Intent i = new Intent(Twitter.this, TwitterWebView.class);
            i.putExtra("url", Uri.parse(url).toString());
            startActivityForResult(i, 1);
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    }
}
```

WebView for Twitter:

```
 public class TwitterWebView extends Activity {

    String url;
    WebView TwitterWebView;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.twitterwebview);

        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        url = extras.getString("url");

        try {
            TwitterWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.wvTwitter);
            TwitterWebView.setWebViewClient(new TwitterWebViewClient(){
                public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                    view.loadUrl(url);
                    return true;
                }
            });
            TwitterWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            TwitterWebView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
            TwitterWebView.getSettings().setSavePassword(false);
            TwitterWebView.getSettings().setSaveFormData(false);
            TwitterWebView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(false);
            TwitterWebView.loadUrl(url);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="wixanz.app.twitter"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <activity
        android:name=".Twitter"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:launchMode="singleInstance" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".TwitterWebView"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".TweetList"
        android:label="TweetList"
        android:launchMode="singleInstance" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data
                android:host="callback"
                android:scheme="twitter" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did the same about others networks like LinkedIn, Foursquare. But instead of use the callback URL, I override the method [`shouldOverrideUrlLoading (WebView view, String url)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#shouldOverrideUrlLoading%28android.webkit.WebView,%20java.lang.String%29) in your WebViewClient (which is used to show the login page) to catch the access token and the token secret (if needed) by myself.

Comment: Thait is to say if I catch tokens then finish() this activity(WebView) and go to a certain activity? How is better to redirect to another activity from WebView by Intent or there are another easier way?

Comment: Actually, you just have to have a WebViewClient (with the visibility set at View.GONE) in your activity.

When a user want to link an account, you display this webView (visibility set to View.VISIBLE) and load the login URL in this webView. 

When the user will confirm his logo/password, the webview will redirect him to a specific URL that contains the information you want. Just to be sure, make a test like `if (url.startsWith(OAUTH_CALLBACK_URL)) {` in the `shouldOverrideUrlLoading` overrided method.

Comment: I did what you say but I get another problem. I wrote next code:
if (url.startsWith(Constants.OAUTH_CALLBACK_URL)) { TwitterWebView.setVisibility(View.GONE);}
However, when my callback is caught I am redirected on Twitter Activity. But I didn`t understand why this activity becomes without any images, buttons and textviews. What is that?
Once more question, how can I redirect on another activity?